# Plotting with different scaled interval using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm wondering if it's possible using matplotlib to plot a serie as a line
defining different ranges whose "zoom level" is different.

Example: let's suppose to plot a series of cartesian coordinates as a line chart. I'd like to divide the x axis space in way for each interval I'd like to define a "zoom" level, determined by the x ticks position. 
In fact it'd be useful to focus on a certain interval stretching it out and thus reducing the plotted space of remaining intervals.

Thanks,

FB

Comment: It is for sure possible. But it's not too clear what exactly you are looking for. Maybe it is what [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306099/how-to-put-different-in-magnitude-values-at-same-distance-on-x-axis) is about?

Comment: It looks interesting and I'll have a deep look asap.